# there should be some indicator to a Q&A if it's used in another question.

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed

At times I ask a question and then get an answer. At times, the answers prompt another question where I share the link of the original Q&A . There should be a way to indicate to the original question about the new question. This way both the answerer and people who were interested in the original question also get the related question/s which were asked.

It would and should increase both the attention span as well as possibility of the new question to be answered as well.

Case in point - The latest question I asked.  [bootable live usb doesn't boot, KNOPPIX](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233627/bootable-live-usb-doesnt-boot-knoppix)

This comes from blogging where people do it all the time using old links to also drive traffic to old posts as well. While this isn't supposed to hard-core commercial site, finding relevant content also is a bit difficult due to limited tag creation and finding content which is relevant to what you are searching.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're looking for the "linked" box in the sidebar:

[image]

Any time a question, one of its answers, or a comment links to another post, both posts will show links to each other in that box

Comment: damn, now how didn't I see that one :(